# What does "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar"?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run an example as it is pointed in [Hadoop in Action book](http://www.manning.com/lam/)  page 15. 
this is the command that needs to be run :

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar
```

but I get this error

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar"
```

It seems like a classpath issue or something. Can someone point out some guideline ?

Actually I am not able to run any of hadoop commands like version, fs, jar ... and so on .. !

NOTE: I am using windows.

Comment: Ok guys, following [this article](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/#comment-87) I was able to solve the problem on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]
Okay, i was reading too fast, you mentioned you were not able to run `hadoop fs` commands as well. I guess you might miss a few congifurations or haven't start the services at all. Try following this [tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) step by step.

---

you will need to pass in the class name, for example:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount [input] [output]
```

Comment: Thanks did I forget to mention that I am using WINDOWS :)

Comment: well, i don't think it has too much difference. Can you run `jps` check if your Namenode is running?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably so late answer, but any way.

Just check that HADOOP_PREFIX environment variable is set correctly (points to your hadoop installed directory).

Comment: this is way too vague, what do you mean by hadoop installed directory, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

you need check your environment variable HADOOP_PREFIX=/path/to/hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as follows in your `~/.bashrc` worked for me:

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw $(hadoop classpath)):$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

As described in documentation: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

**You have to set HADOOP_PREFIX pointing to your hadoop installation folder.**

This is an example script to start in stand-alone mode:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/hadoop-2.6.5/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/etc/hadoop-2.6.5

mkdir input
cp etc/hadoop/*.xml input
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.5.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
cat output/*
```