# Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar on windows 10

Tags: hadoop

Similar problem like in:
[What does "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522115/what-does-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-hadoop-util-runja)

but those solutions do not work for me.

I have downloaded hadoop from http://ftp.man.poznan.pl/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.1.2/hadoop-3.1.2.tar.gz and put in in `D:` and in file: `hadoop-3.1.2\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.sh` I have put:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=D:/hadoop-3.1.2
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_PREFIX=D:/installed/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.2
export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop
```

using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variables. [To find where environment variables are.](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

1) **Setting up HADOOP_HOME**
Click on New to set up new environment. A screen will appear with text fields Variable name and variable value.

**Variable name:** `HADOOP_HOME`

**Variable Value:** `D:/hadoop-3.1.2`

Verify by using `echo %HADOOP_HOME%` in CMD.

2) Setting up path for bin and sbin

Edit the existing **PATH** and at the end of **Variable Value**, put a semi colon and paste the following path:-

`$HADOOP_HOME/sbin;$HADOOP_HOME/bin`

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10

Comment: Hadoop isn't that reliable with Windows. I suggest you to move onto Linux. Try to install a virtual machine and run Hadoop in Pseudo distributed mode. https://www.edureka.co/community/3444/difference-between-single-pseudo-distributed-mode-hadoop

Comment: yeee, before i was practicing hadoop with hortonworks set on virtual RedHat but now I am following book "Hadoop in action" where author encourages to set hadoop on windows, but not gives any clues how to fight with problems... I think I will move to linux as ya suggest.

Comment: If you look at official documentation on Apache Hadoop. They demonstrated Hadoop on Linux. Everyone uses Hadoop on Linux. I will prefer the book: Hadoop the definitive guide. This book will provide you all the details about Hadoop. It's the best book so far for learning Hadoop.